# What is wrong with my makefile? I get an "undefined reference" error

Tags: c, makefile

I'm pretty new to c coding and I've checked the standard references on makefiles but I seem to be misunderstanding something because I'm getting an error. If anybody can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Here it is:

```
#makefile

all: runme dontrunme

runme: runme.o 
    clang runme.o -o runme

dontrunme: dontrunme.o library.o fun.o
    clang dontrunme.o -o dontrunme

runme.o: library.o runme.c
    clang -c runme.c -o runme.o

dontrunme.o: dontrunme.c
    clang -c dontrunme.c -o dontrunme.o

library.o: library.c library.h
    clang -c library.c -o library.o

fun.o: fun.c fun.h
    clang -c fun.c -o fun.o


clean:
    rm  -f *.o runme dontrunme
```

The error I get when I type `make` is:

```
runme.o:runme.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'reverse'
```

`reverse` is a function whose protoype is in `library.h` and is defined in `library.c`

Any help in understanding where I went wrong is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the code for runme.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "library.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  char s[] = "Hello World!";

  printf("%s\n", s);

  reverse(s);

  printf("%s\n", s);

}
```

Comment: show us the sourcecode for `runme.c`

Comment: That is not problem with `makefile`, but compilation error. Are you including `library.h` in `runme.c`?

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for commenting. Yes, I am including library.h in runme.c and this is a problem for which all but the makefile was provided so it must be a problem with my makefile. As requested, I edited the question to show the source of runme.c

Comment: @user3339901 please remove source of `runme.c` from here and paste it in your question window.Also all header and source file lies in same folder where your `makefile` exist?

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
runme: runme.o 
    clang runme.o -o runme
```

to this:

```
runme: runme.o library.o
    clang runme.o library.o -o runme
```

And do the same for `dontrunme`

```
dontrunme: dontrunme.o library.o fun.o
    clang dontrunme.o library.o fun.o -o dontrunme
```

In both cases you're not including all the object code files in your final links.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the filename order dependency is for library files, not object files (and despite the name `library.o` isn't a library file).

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks Michael. I don't use unix cmd-line tools nearly enough to remember the specifics. I used to (a long, long time ago). I knew crap can get tossed out somewhere in there. Thank you very much for the clarification. section clipped.

Comment: I should clarify - order of object files can matter with respect to libraries (ie., if a library is listed before an object file and the object file depends on that lib there might be a build error because the library dependencies might not get pulled in). I think that a good rule of thumb is to list object files before libraries and put the libraries in order such that the libraries that depend on other libraries come first.  Unless you know for sure that you need a different order (and can explain why).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I completely concur. That is near-verbatim how I usually setup makes when crafting them.

Answer (score 0):

please change order in `makefile` as follows. you first need `library.o` for build `runme.o`
so please build `library.o` first then `runme.o`

```
library.o: library.c library.h
    clang -c library.c -o library.o


runme.o: library.o runme.c
    clang -c runme.c -o runme.o
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answe. However, I made the suggested change to the order and am still getting the same error.